# Call a single html form from Google sheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, popup

I a Google Spreadsheet filling from html form.
Function `processForm` works well and all fields are getting correct data
My problem with `launchForm` as I'm thinking.
The form opens in a popup window, but inputs don't load `datalist` elements. Unfortunately I don't understand why

```js
function launchForm() {
  var htmlApp = HtmlService
      .createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')  
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)      
      .setWidth(400) 
      .setHeight(450);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(htmlApp);
}

  
  function processForm(formObject) {
    var url = "LINK_TO_SPREADSHEET_OF_DATA_COLLECTION";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("List");
    var asiaTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
    var nameParam = [ws.getLastRow(),
                    formObject.recipe_name,
                    formObject.place_name,
                    formObject.servingOrder,
                    formObject.cuisine_name,
                    asiaTime]
    ws.appendRow(nameParam);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                        <p class="h4 mb-4 text-center">New Recipe</p>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="recipe_name">Recipe Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipe_name" name="recipe_name" placeholder="Recipe Name" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="cuisine_name">Cuisine</label>
                                <input id="cuisine_name" name="cuisine_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cuisine Name" list="cuisine_name" required>
                                    <datalist id="cuisine_name">
                                    <option value="Asian"></option>
                                    <option value="Western"></option>                                    
                                    </datalist>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <p>Place name</p>
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="place_name" id="ll4h" value="LL4H" required>
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="ll4h">LL4H</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="place_name" id="ll4t" value="LL4T" required>
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="female">LL4T</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="servingOrder">Serving order</label>  
                                <input id="servingOrder" name="servingOrder" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Serving order" list="servingOrder" required>
                                    <datalist id="servingOrder">
                                    <option value="Starter"></option>
                                    <option value="Main course"></option> 
                                    <option value="Veggi side"></option>
                                    <option value="Carbs side"></option>
                                    <option value="Dessert"></option>
                                    <option value="Dough"></option>
                                    <option value="Sauce"></option>
                                    <option value="Drink"></option>
                                    <option value="Other"></option>                                                                       
                                    </datalist>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                    <div id="output"></div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
        <script>
            // Prevent forms from submitting.
            function preventFormSubmit() {
              var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
              for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
                forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                });
              }
            }
            window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);    
                
                
            function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
              google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
              document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
              
            }
          </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where I'm wrong and how to fix it? What is the best way to close popup after submitting?

Answer (score 1):

- You want to put `datalist` to the input tag.

For this, how about this answer? I think that the reason of your issue is that the same `id` is used to the input tag and the datalist tag. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
<input id="cuisine_name" name="cuisine_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cuisine Name" list="cuisine_name" required>
<datalist id="cuisine_name">
```

#### To:

```
<input id="cuisine_name" name="cuisine_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cuisine Name" list="cuisine_name_datalist" required>
<datalist id="cuisine_name_datalist">
```

And

#### From:

```
<input id="servingOrder" name="servingOrder" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Serving order" list="servingOrder" required>
<datalist id="servingOrder">
```

#### To:

```
<input id="servingOrder" name="servingOrder" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Serving order" list="servingOrder_datalist" required>
<datalist id="servingOrder_datalist">
```

#### Reference:

- [The HTML Data List element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's does not work for me. It works when I deploy it as web app. But i want to fill this form in a popup window. Could you recommend what I have to check to fix it, please?

Comment: @Timogavk Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `but it's does not work for me. It works when I deploy it as web app. But i want to fill this form in a popup window.`. Because in my environment, when above modification is reflected to your script, I could confirm that the modified script worked. So can I ask you about the detail of your current situation? If you can do, please provide the script for replicating your current issue. I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Timogavk Unfortunately, I cannot still replicate `The form opens in a popup window, but inputs don't load datalist elements`. from your replying. When the modification in my answer is reflected, the datalist elements can be loaded for both Web Apps and the opened dialog. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So can you provide the your script for replicating it? If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Timogavk Can I ask you whether you can cooperate to resolve your issue?

Comment: You resolve it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61566169/how-to-run-html-from-google-library/61567615?noredirect=1#comment108908067_61567615

Comment: It was the problem with library

Comment: @Timogavk Thank you for replying. I couldn't notice that your this question uses the GAS library. So I tested above script without the library and I had confirmed that the modified script worked. I apologize for this.