# How to run HTML from google library?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Library with HTML form, process form script `addNewItem`and script to run the form in popup window `addItem`.

```js
function addItem()
{
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('input/form.html');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Add New Recipe');
  
}

function addNewItem(form_data)
{
  var url = "SPREADSHEET_URL_TO_DATA_COLLECTION";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('List');  
  var asiaTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
  
  var dishName = form_data.dish_name;
  var cuisineName = form_data.cuisine_name;
  var placeName = form_data.place_name;
  var categoryName = form_data.category_name;
  var num = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValue() + 1 || sheet.getLastRow();
    
  sheet.appendRow([num, dishName, cuisineName, placeName, categoryName, asiaTime]);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myform">
    <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="dish_name">Dish name</label>
    <input type='text' name='dish_name' id="dish_name" required="required"/>
    </div>
   
    <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="place_name">Place</label>
        <select id="place_name" name="place_name" type="text" required>
       
             <option value="LL4H">LL4H</option>
             <option value="LL4T">LL4T</option>              
        </select>
    </div>
    
    <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="cuisine_name">Cuisine</label>
        <select id="cuisine_name" name="cuisine_name" type="text" required>
       
             <option value="Asian">Asian</option>
             <option value="Western">Western</option>              
        </select>
    </div>
    
    <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="category_name">Category</label>
        <input id="category_name" name="category_name" type="text" list="quote-choices" required>
        <datalist id="quote-choices">
             <option value="Starter">Starter</option>
             <option value="Main course">Main course</option> 
             <option value="Veggi side">Veggi side</option>
             <option value="Carbs side">Carbs side</option>
             <option value="Dessert">Dessert</option>
             <option value="Dough">Dough</option>
             <option value="Sauce">Sauce</option>
             <option value="Drink">Drink</option>
             <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </datalist>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    <button type="submit" class="action">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script>
      document.querySelector("#myform").addEventListener("submit", 
      function(e)
      {
      e.preventDefault();    //stop form from submitting
      console.log(this)
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(()=> google.script.host.close()).addNewItem(this);
      }
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I connected this Library with the Google Spreadsheet and declared new function to run library script to open the form.

```js
function createRecipe() {
  RecipeBuilder.addItem();
}

function addNewItem(form_data) {
  RecipeBuilder.addNewItem(form_data);
}
```

Form appears in popup window well.

[image]

I click `Submit` to submit my data from the form, but serverside process does not start.

How to run this form correct? Where I'm wrong? How to fix it?

---

### UPDATED

It's still does not work with library but works well if I put it in bound-container script of some spreadsheet. Unfortunately, I can't use it in bound-container because full code of `addNewItem(form_data)` function must replicate current spreadsheet. Finally it will be 1000+ Google Spreadsheets with same numbers of bound-containers. It will be super complicated to update it

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You want to use `addItem()`, `addNewItem(form_data)` and `input/form.html` as a GAS library.
- When you call this library from the client side, when the submit button is clicked, the data is not sent.

  - You want to remove this issue.
- The library name is `RecipeBuilder`.

For this, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- I think that the reason of your issue is `google.script.run.addNewItem(this);`. In this case, when `addNewItem(this)` is run, this function is searched from the GAS project. By this, an error occurs like `Uncaught TypeError: google.script.run.addNewItem is not a function`. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

In order to remove this issue, how about the following modification? In this modification, one more function is added to the client side.

#### Modified script:

```
function createRecipe() {
  RecipeBuilder.addItem();
}

// Added
function addNewItem(form_data) {
  RecipeBuilder.addNewItem(form_data);
}
```

- By this, when `google.script.run.addNewItem(this);` is run at the library side, `addNewItem` of client side is run, and then, `RecipeBuilder.addNewItem` of the library side is run.

#### Note:

- In your Javascript of library side, `google.script.run.addNewItem(this);` and `google.script.host.close();` are run in order. But `google.script.run` works with the asynchronous process. So if the process of `addNewItem(this)` is slow, the dialog might be closed before `addNewItem(this)` is run. So I think that the following modification might be also used.

  - From

    ```
    google.script.run.addNewItem(this);
    google.script.host.close();//close this dialogbox
    ```
  - To

    ```
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(()=> google.script.host.close()).addNewItem(this);
    ```

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Thank you very much! I was very close to this solution, but knowledge still very poor. 
One more question. How can I get log in console? Because now I see `addItem()` log only without `addNewItem()`

Comment: @Timogavk Thank you for replying. At first, can I ask you whether my proposal resolved your issue? Because I cannot understand about `I was very close to this solution, but knowledge still very poor.`. About your new question, unfortunately, I cannot understand about `How can I get log in console? Because now I see addItem() log only without addNewItem()`. From this, I cannot understand about what you want to do. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: I just asked about how to log server side scripts

Comment: @Timogavk Thank you for replying. You want to retrieve the log in Google Apps Script side in the GAS library. If my understanding is correct, in that case, you can retrieve the log by putting `console.log("sample")` to the function of `addItem` and `addNewItem` in the library. When you run the function `createRecipe` at the client, for example, you can confirm the log at [Stackdriver logs for other executions are available in the Apps Script Dashboard](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging) and [here](https://script.google.com/home/executions).

Comment: @Timogavk When the function you ran is opened at Apps Script Dashboard, you can see the log at Stackdriver logs.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you put your scripts into:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
    // your code here
});
```